# How to use AERT_Allocate with std:vector

Tags: c++, audio, stdvector

I am writing a Windows Audio Processing Object (APO) driver and currently using `std::vector<float>` for convenience to manage buffering of audio.

I note the MS requirement that I can use only locked memory and that there is available a handy utility for this: [AERT_Allocate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/baseaudioprocessingobject/nf-baseaudioprocessingobject-aert_allocate)

I would like to be able to use `AERT_Allocate` with my `std::vector<float>`.
Can someone please provide guidance/code snippet as to how I can do this, or do I have to revert to using a pure C array or some other structure in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: You have to write your own allocator which invokes AERT_Allocate upon allocation call, and use it as a vector's template argument. Here are the requirements: [Allocator named requirements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator)

Comment: Thanks @RafałGórczewski - this is really useful

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector` actually doesn't allocate any memory at all, since it is done by allocators, which can be provided upon vector's construction. Vector only manages memory, that allocator allocates. It uses [std::allocator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator) by default, but you can easily write your own allocator utilizing `AERT_Allocate`. It has to meet the [allocator named requirements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator) though, meaning that you have to provide a sufficient interface for templates to work with.

For example, you will probably want to put `AERT_Allocate` in your allocator's `allocate()` member function, which is one of the allocator's named requirements.